# Recordmydesktop and Kazam stop button is not showing in top panel

Tags: recordmydesktop, kazam

I have installed recordmydesktop and kazam in ubuntu 18.04.

I have pressed start recording button, the video gets
started, but there is not stop button appearing on the
top panel. Hence unable to stop the recording.
I have to logout to stop the recording.
I have installed kazam also, it has also the same problem.

I have ubuntu 16.04 in another system also. 
I am having the same problem in that system also.

I have searched the web and none of the solutions are 
working.